OpenSearch Alert Trigger Timeout Issue: Manual Email Test Succeeds, Alert Notification Fails
My problem is OpenSearch smtp connection timeout error. Manual Email Test Works but alert notification fails due to timeout issue.
When I want to try the smtp connection on editing monitory screen, it sends mail succesfully.

But with the same configuration when i trigger an alert, OpenSearch says timeout error.

I am using v 2.11.1 version of OpenSearch.
